# how can i use two databases with spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, datasource

I trying to use two databases in my project so i follow this link:

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources)

but just like example i create one Interface and extend CrudRepository

```
public interface UsuarioRepository extends CrudRepository<TbUsuario, Long>{}
```

so where i use?

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.secondDatasource")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

to specify my datasource??

Comment: Here is a good example on [how to configure jpa repositories using different datasource and transaction manager](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure two Datasources, two EntityManagerFactories, and two TransactionManagers. Have a look at section [67.7 Use Two EntityManagers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-use-two-entity-managers) in the Spring Boot docs and [4.1.2. Annotation based configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.java-config) in the Spring Data JPA docs. You also need to disable datasource auto configuration in the Application class. An example showing how to put all this stuff together can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources). Good luck!