# Spring Boot with two datasources: How to setup unique resource names?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, atomikos

As [pointed out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources), you can define two Datasources in Spring Boot in the following way:

```
#first db
spring.datasource.url = [url]
spring.datasource.username = [username]
spring.datasource.password = [password]
spring.datasource.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

#second db ...
spring.secondDatasource.url = [url]
spring.secondDatasource.username = [username]
spring.secondDatasource.password = [password]
spring.secondDatasource.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver


@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.secondDatasource")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

This seems to work fine. But when you are doing Atomikos XA-Transactions, each datasource has to has a unique resource name for the case that a recovery is necessary.

The [Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) defines a property for this:

```
spring.jta.atomikos.datasource.unique-resource-name=dataSource # The unique name used to identify the resource during recovery.
```

How do I provide a unique-resource-name for the primary and a different one for the secondary resource in Spring Boot?

Looks to me like XA-Transactions are supported in Boot, but only between JMS and DB ressources...