# Spring Boot Multiple MySQL Databases

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a MySQL server that contains around 15 Databases (each database has between 5-20 tables). (Not my choice and not something that is able to be changed)

I have read several stackoverflow posts, baeldung, etc, which all talk about multiple data sources but seem to mean using Postgres/MySQL, or MySQL/H2. I am searching for a scalable solution for MySQL that allows for several databases to be used.

I am somewhat new to Spring, but not to Java, so I may just be missing something. This would be an example of my properties file.

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.database1.db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database1
spring.datasource.database1.db.username=user
spring.datasource.database1.db.password=password
spring.datasource.database1.db.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.database1.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.database1.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.database1.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.datasource.database1.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.database2.db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database2
spring.datasource.database2.db.username=user
spring.datasource.database2.db.password=password
spring.datasource.database2.db.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.database2.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.database2.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.database2.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.datasource.database2.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.database3.db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database3
spring.datasource.database3.db.username=user
spring.datasource.database3.db.password=password
spring.datasource.database3.db.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.database3.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.database3.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.database3.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.datasource.database3.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I feel that the jpa portion of the properties are redundant, but when I tried to reuse them in the config file, it complained and wouldn't compile. I am not sure how to reuse the @ConfigurationProperties.

My file structure would contain a folder for each database, which would in turn have folders for each of the models, controllers, repositories, etc. For example:

`Project
│   pom.xml
│   manifest.yml
│
└───src
    └───main
        └───java
        |   └───com
        |       └───myorg
        |           |   Application.java
        |           └───config
        |           |   |    DatabaseConfig.java
        |           |
        |           └───databases
        |               └───database1
        |               |   |   Database1Config.java
        |               |   └───models
        |               |   |   |   TableA.java
        |               |   |   |   TableB.java
        |               |   |   |   TableC.java
        |               |   |
        |               |   └───controllers
        |               |   |   |   TableAController.java
        |               |   |   |   TableBController.java
        |               |   |   |   TableCController.java
        |               |   |
        |               |   └───repositories
        |               |       |   TableARepository.java
        |               |       |   TableBRepository.java
        |               |       |   TableCRepository.java
        |               |
        |               └───database2
        |                   |   Database2Config.java
        |                   └───models
        |                   |   |   TableD.java
        |                   |   |   TableE.java
        |                   |   |   TableF.java
        |                   |
        |                   └───controllers
        |                   |   |   TableEController.java
        |                   |   |   TableDController.java
        |                   |   |   TableFController.java
        |                   |
        |                   └───repositories
        |                       |   TableDRepository.java
        |                       |   TableERepository.java
        |                       |   TableFRepository.java
        |
        └───resources
            |   application.properties`

Essentially, this is what I would like to have as a file structure, knowing that it will be growing with tables in the future. If there is something else that makes more sense, I am all ears.

If anyone could provide a link to documentation that describes what I need, that would be great. I am not looking for someone to code for me, just need to be pointed in the correct direction.

Please let me know if more clarification is needed. Thanks!

Comment: Properties support only single instance of the database, if you need multiple instances then you'll have to create beans for them yourself. Checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30344608/5343269

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate provides multi-tenancy which allows for dynamically switching between  multiple schemas or databases. The [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy) describe it in more detail. A more spring-oriented example can i.e. be found [here](https://dzone.com/articles/multi-tenancy-using-jpa-spring-and-hibernate-part) and [here](https://dzone.com/articles/multi-tenancy-using-jpa-spring-and-hibernate-part-2).