# Spring Boot connect Mysql and MongoDb

Tags: mysql, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a problem with Spring Boot application. I want to connect a MongoDB database and a MySql database in my Spring boot application. I would to know if it is possible, in positive case How I can make this multiple connection. I had made a try based on an example with Mysql and Post without success. So I'm wondering if someone have an easy example to know the method. 
thanks

Comment: Hii, have you succeeded in connecting both MySQL and MongoDb to your springboot project?

Answer (score 14):

It is possible to do this.you will have create different configuration for different datasources. This link has good examples on that
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Another useful stackoverflow question: [Spring Boot Configure and Use Two DataSources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources)

To get started with mongo and mysql , you can follow example from spring.io guides.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

**EDIT :**

I have created this one example, merging two samples above

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

import hello.model.Customer;
import hello.model.User;
import hello.mongodao.CustomerRepository;
import hello.mysqldao.UserRepository;

@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = CustomerRepository.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories (basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("getting data from Mongo");
        repository.deleteAll();

        // save a couple of customers
        repository.save(new Customer("Alice", "Smith"));
        repository.save(new Customer("Bob", "Smith"));

        // fetch all customers
        System.out.println("Customers found with findAll():");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : repository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
        System.out.println();

        // fetch an individual customer
        System.out.println("Customer found with findByFirstName('Alice'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println(repository.findByFirstName("Alice"));

        System.out.println("Customers found with findByLastName('Smith'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : repository.findByLastName("Smith")) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }

        System.out.println("gettting data from mysql");
        userRepository.deleteAll();

        // save a couple of customers
        userRepository.save(new User("Alice", "Alice@Smith.com"));
        userRepository.save(new User("Bob", "Bob@Smith.com"));

        // fetch all customers
        System.out.println("Users found with findAll():");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");

        for (User user : userRepository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(user);
        }

    }
}
```

CustomerRepository.java

```
package hello.mongodao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import hello.model.Customer;

public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {

    public Customer findByFirstName(String firstName);
    public List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);

}
```

UserRepository.java

```
package hello.mysqldao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import hello.model.User;

// This will be AUTO IMPLEMENTED by Spring into a Bean called userRepository
// CRUD refers Create, Read, Update, Delete

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

Customer.java

```
package hello.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;


public class Customer {

    @Id
    public String id;

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;

    public Customer() {}

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%s, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName);
    }

}
```

User.java

```
package hello.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String email;
public User() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
    public User(String string, String string2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        name = string;
        email = string2;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "User[id=%s, name='%s', email='%s']",
                id, name, email);
    }


}
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/local
```

Comment: I want to use two mongodb databse, in my application.properties: `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/databasename`, when I want to use another mongodb databse, should I add another same application.properties ? and how I distinguish it when I use it?

Comment: that's helped me much: ignoring of parametrization of @EnableJpa/MongoRepositories or even one of them cause the strange non-clear errors on beans initialization.

Comment: I tried this but i get this message: The bean 'userMigrationDataRepository', defined in UserMigrationDataRepository defined in EnableJpaRepositories declared on UsersApplication, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in UserMigrationDataRepository defined in EnableMongoRepositories declared on UsersApplication and overriding is disabled.

Comment: @CarlosAndres Add two packages in your repository package(one for mongo and another one for mysql. Move all your repositories of Mongo to mongo package and all your mysql repositories to mysql package. Then add this in you main class: 
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.yourpackagename.repository.mongo"})

Answer (score 9):

You really don't need to make additional config and property files because MongoDB has different property names than sql so all you will need is an application.properties file

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/dbName?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=

spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=dbName
```

example models

MongoDB document

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import javax.persistence.Id;

    @Document("Gyros")
    public class Gyros {
    
        public Gyros(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
    
        @Id
        public String id;
    
        public String description;
    }
```

Mysql JPA entity

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Kebab")
public class Kebab {

    public Kebab(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Kebab() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;

    public String description;
}
```

MongoDB repository

```
@Repository
public interface GyrosRepository extends MongoRepository<Gyros, String> {
}
```

Mysql Jpa repository

```
    @Repository
    public interface KebabRepository extends JpaRepository<Kebab, Integer> {
    }
```

TestService

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class Service {

    private final GyrosRepository gyrosRepository;
    private final KebabRepository kebabRepository;

    @Autowired
    public Service(GyrosRepository gyrosRepository, KebabRepository kebabRepository) {
        this.gyrosRepository = gyrosRepository;
        this.kebabRepository = kebabRepository;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void test() {
        this.gyrosRepository.insert(new Gyros("ham ham"));
        this.kebabRepository.saveAndFlush(new Kebab("yum yum"));
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>stack</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>stackoverflow</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Your solution works!

I'm wondering, how did you get rid of this warning on starting the application:
Spring Data JPA - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface 'repository' If you want this repository to be a JPA repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these ...

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same kind of problem once. I had to connect my spring boot application to two different databases. One was Mongo db and other was Postgres db.

You can see that i have used both JPA as well as spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb. Still my project is running absolutely fine.Hope for you also it work successfully. There are suggestions over the internet to not use JPA but i am not able to use JPA repository without include JPA.

Here I am posting the solution which worked for me.

Hope it helps someone:

1. application.properties file:

   ## MONGODB (MongoProperties)

   spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://XX.XX.XX.XX:27017/testdb

   ```
   #POSTGRES properties
       spring.datasource.platform=postgres
       spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database_name    
       spring.datasource.username=postgres_usr_name
       spring.datasource.password=postgres_pwd
       spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
   ```
2. My pom dependencies:

   ```
   <dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
   </dependency>   
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
       <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
   </dependency> 
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
       <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
   </dependency> 
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. To access my data Using Repositories:

   (i): MONGO REPOSITORY

   ```
     import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
       public interface MRepositories extends MongoRepository<YourEntityClass, String>{
           }
   ```

   (ii): JPA repository

   ```
   @Repository public interface PostGresRepo extends JpaRepository<TestEntity,Long> {}
   ```