# Spring boot mongodb application configuration

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm creating spring boot micro service application. One micro service use spring boot and MySQL and hibernate. Another micro service use spring boot and mongodb. Below you can see Spring boot main application of micro-service which is use spring boot and MySQL and hibernate.

```
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"com.saman.kamak.nimal.sunilservice"})
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.saman.kamak.nimal.sunilservice"})
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.saman.kamak.nimal.sunilservice.repository"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.saman.kamak.nimal.sunilservice.domain"})
public class ColdApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ColdApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now I'm creating a micro-service with spring boot & mongodb. How does main class of it appear like? How should it change this one                                   `@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.saman.kamak.nimal.sunilservice.domain"})`

Is it `@documentScan(basePackages = {"com.saman.kamak.nimal.sunilservice.domain"})`

Below you can see my mongodb model class

```
import java.io.Serializable;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Document
public class Cold implements Serializable {

   private static final Long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Id
      private String box;
      private String pencil;
      private String pen;
      private String bag;
      private String phone;
}
```

Comment: You can look into this answer -> [configuring mongo and mysql in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44508317/2190218)

Comment: Please refer this https://paulsofts.com/crud-operations-how-to-integrate-spring-boot-with-monogdb

Answer (score 0):

For Configuring MongoDB with your spring boot app follow the below steps:

- Add MongoDB starter dependency (for maven add below in your pom.xml ):

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Add Below configurations in your property file application.properties:

MongoDB Credentials

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=your_db_user 
spring.data.mongodb.password=your_db_password
spring.data.mongodb.database=your_db_name
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017 
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
```

Your main class would be something like below:

```
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"com.saman.kamak.nimal.sunilservice"})
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.saman.kamak.nimal.sunilservice"})
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ={"com.saman.kamak.nimal.sunilservice.repository"})
public class DemoRestApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoRestApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```