# Spring boot data jpa multiple datasources entityManagerFactory error

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, multiple-databases

I want to use two databases with Spring Boot. Here the code:

first db config

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"net.elyland.pipe.repositories.router"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "routerEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "routerTransactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"net.elyland.pipe.domain.router"})
public class RouterRepositoryConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "routerDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "router.datasource")
    public DataSource routerDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .build();
    }

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "routerPU")
    @Bean(name = "routerEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean routerEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("routerDataSource")DataSource routerDataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(routerDataSource)
                .properties(hibernateProperties())
                .packages(Ip.class, Net.class, Provider.class, QueueRule.class, QueueType.class,RemoteIp.class,Subnet.class,TrafficQueue.class)
                .persistenceUnit("routerPU")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "routerTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager mysqlTransactionManager(@Qualifier("routerEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    private Map hibernateProperties() {

        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("routerHibernate.properties");

        try {
            Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);

            return properties.entrySet().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            e -> e.getKey().toString(),
                            e -> e.getValue())
                    );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new HashMap();
        }
    }
}
```

Second db config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackageClasses = {SshUser.class, User.class, Role.class},
        basePackages = {"net.elyland.pipe.domain.admin"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "adminEntityManager" ,
        transactionManagerRef = "adminTransactionManager"
        )
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties" })
public class AdminRepositoryConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "adminDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "admin.datasource")

    public DataSource adminDataSource() {
        System.out.println("Create datasource Admin");
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "adminEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean adminEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("adminDataSource") DataSource adminDataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(adminDataSource)
                .properties(hibernateProperties())
                .packages(User.class, LocalIp.class, CommandLog.class, PipeSize.class, Role.class,Rule.class,Server.class,SshUser.class)
                .persistenceUnit("adminPU")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "adminTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager adminTransactionManager(@Qualifier("adminEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    private Map hibernateProperties() {

        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("hibernate.properties");

        try {
            Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);

            return properties.entrySet().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            e -> e.getKey().toString(),
                            e -> e.getValue())
                    );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new HashMap();
        }
    }
}
```

Repository 1:

```
@Repository
@Transactional("adminTransactionManager")
public interface SshUserRepository extends JpaRepository<SshUser, Integer> {
    SshUser findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Repository 2:

```
@Repository
@Transactional("routerTransactionManager")
public interface SubnetRepository extends JpaRepository<Subnet, Integer> {
    public Subnet findByAddress(Integer address);
    public Subnet findByMask(Integer mask);
}
```

properties file:

```
admin.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.3:3306/pipe?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
admin.datasource.username=user
admin.datasource.password=pass
admin.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

router.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.3:3306/router?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
router.datasource.username=user
router.datasource.password=pass
router.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

hibernate.properties:

```
#spring.jpa.show-sql = true
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
```

At the start I have this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userRepository in net.elyland.pipe.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

Here the full log:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.1.RELEASE)

2017-07-07 18:52:18.774  INFO 11870 --- [           main] n.e.pipe.SpringBootMvcJspApplication     : Starting SpringBootMvcJspApplication on adm-imaterynko with PID 11870 (/home/imaterynko/SVN/sysadm/javawebdev/pipe/target/classes started by imaterynko in /home/imaterynko/SVN/sysadm/javawebdev/pipe)
2017-07-07 18:52:18.780  INFO 11870 --- [           main] n.e.pipe.SpringBootMvcJspApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-07-07 18:52:18.859  INFO 11870 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6a472554: startup date [Fri Jul 07 18:52:18 EEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-07-07 18:52:20.485  INFO 11870 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'remoteIpRepository' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2017-07-07 18:52:20.487  INFO 11870 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'providerRepository' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2017-07-07 18:52:20.488  INFO 11870 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'netRepository' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2017-07-07 18:52:20.491  INFO 11870 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'queueTypeRepository' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2017-07-07 18:52:20.492  INFO 11870 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'ipRepository' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2017-07-07 18:52:20.494  INFO 11870 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'subnetRepository' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2017-07-07 18:52:20.497  INFO 11870 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'queueRuleRepository' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2017-07-07 18:52:20.504  INFO 11870 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'trafficQueueRepository' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2017-07-07 18:52:21.046  INFO 11870 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-07 18:52:21.110  INFO 11870 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'validator' of type [class org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-07 18:52:21.158  INFO 11870 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee2486b5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-07 18:52:21.170  INFO 11870 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'objectPostProcessor' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-07 18:52:21.172  INFO 11870 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@678040b3' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-07 18:52:21.180  INFO 11870 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$12f92967] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-07 18:52:21.193  INFO 11870 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-07 18:52:21.203  INFO 11870 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5576be7b] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-07 18:52:21.537  INFO 11870 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-07-07 18:52:21.551  INFO 11870 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-07-07 18:52:21.552  INFO 11870 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-07-07 18:52:22.039  INFO 11870 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2017-07-07 18:52:22.042  INFO 11870 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-07-07 18:52:22.042  INFO 11870 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3185 ms
2017-07-07 18:52:22.239  INFO 11870 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-07 18:52:22.240  INFO 11870 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2017-07-07 18:52:22.241  INFO 11870 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Filter characterEncodingFilter was not registered (possibly already registered?)
2017-07-07 18:52:22.241  INFO 11870 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
Create datasource Admin
2017-07-07 18:52:22.894  INFO 11870 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'adminPU'
2017-07-07 18:52:22.912  INFO 11870 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: adminPU
    ...]
2017-07-07 18:52:22.971  INFO 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.11.Final}
2017-07-07 18:52:22.973  INFO 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop}
2017-07-07 18:52:22.974  INFO 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-07-07 18:52:23.007  INFO 11870 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-07-07 18:52:23.210  INFO 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2017-07-07 18:52:23.673  INFO 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-07-07 18:52:23.685 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table command_log drop foreign key FKo5wo2sqahur6v6uym1t2sjken
2017-07-07 18:52:23.685 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'pipe.command_log' doesn't exist
2017-07-07 18:52:23.688 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table host drop foreign key FK9hlhx55t325whiraf8newuxcv
2017-07-07 18:52:23.688 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'pipe.host' doesn't exist
2017-07-07 18:52:23.689 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table rule drop foreign key FKeuk4g8c1yhpjno3suq3syen02
2017-07-07 18:52:23.690 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'pipe.rule' doesn't exist
2017-07-07 18:52:23.691 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table rule drop foreign key FKtria2gmd5ghsirwucl003p935
2017-07-07 18:52:23.691 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'pipe.rule' doesn't exist
2017-07-07 18:52:23.693 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table rule drop foreign key FKsoy6c2wf2ahd7y2awnfabuxkc
2017-07-07 18:52:23.694 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'pipe.rule' doesn't exist
2017-07-07 18:52:23.695 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table user drop foreign key FKn82ha3ccdebhokx3a8fgdqeyy
2017-07-07 18:52:23.695 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'pipe.user' doesn't exist
2017-07-07 18:52:24.183  INFO 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-07-07 18:52:24.238  INFO 11870 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'adminPU'
2017-07-07 18:52:24.300  INFO 11870 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'routerPU'
2017-07-07 18:52:24.301  INFO 11870 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: routerPU
    ...]
2017-07-07 18:52:24.386  INFO 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2017-07-07 18:52:24.476  INFO 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-07-07 18:52:24.478 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table ip drop foreign key FKnunykfm5kyqpk69fu78rm690t
2017-07-07 18:52:24.478 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'router.ip' doesn't exist
2017-07-07 18:52:24.479 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table ip drop foreign key FK3fkkinqulfhgjo6c7gu8ptu8f
2017-07-07 18:52:24.479 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'router.ip' doesn't exist
2017-07-07 18:52:24.481 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table ip drop foreign key FK4txj00furhr0boqimj1s0loa1
2017-07-07 18:52:24.481 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'router.ip' doesn't exist
2017-07-07 18:52:24.483 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table queue_rule drop foreign key FK5bm4nnopngcrglm6od8m97yhh
2017-07-07 18:52:24.483 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'router.queue_rule' doesn't exist
2017-07-07 18:52:24.485 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table queue_rule drop foreign key FKohmfk4krumgcaa75kxnfxcwfv
2017-07-07 18:52:24.485 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'router.queue_rule' doesn't exist
2017-07-07 18:52:24.486 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table queue_rule drop foreign key FKtc36dnb4iulun0yn72wqrybf4
2017-07-07 18:52:24.486 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'router.queue_rule' doesn't exist
2017-07-07 18:52:24.487 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table queue_rule drop foreign key FK3t8l9ho5h9g7soqrk94h3van0
2017-07-07 18:52:24.487 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Table 'router.queue_rule' doesn't exist
2017-07-07 18:52:25.003  INFO 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-07-07 18:52:25.007  INFO 11870 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'routerPU'
2017-07-07 18:52:25.124  WARN 11870 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#693f2213' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#693f2213': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
2017-07-07 18:52:25.124  INFO 11870 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'routerPU'
2017-07-07 18:52:25.124  INFO 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-07-07 18:52:25.523  INFO 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-07-07 18:52:25.526  INFO 11870 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'adminPU'
2017-07-07 18:52:25.526  INFO 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-07-07 18:52:25.920  INFO 11870 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-07-07 18:52:25.925  WARN 11870 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available)
2017-07-07 18:52:25.985 ERROR 11870 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userRepository in net.elyland.pipe.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

Can somebody say what's wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Spring Boot makes it easier than whatever it is you are trying to do in your code above. Take a look here for the basics on dealing with multiple data sources: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources. Combine this with one of the Spring Boot tutorials on JPA and throw out what you currently have.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I changed my code but have the same error.  I have tried different configurations but always have had the same error "...required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found". Maybe I miss something impotent.

Comment: I have tried this config - https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-boot-transaction and this example - http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases and have the same error. If I use one db all works fine. I have spent already one week trying to work it whit no result. Please help.

Comment: I cant understand, why my app cant autowire right entitymanager if I defined it in config as entityManagerFactoryRef  transactionManagerRef

Comment: Finally, I don't know why but  it's working with current configuration github.com/manish-in-java/spring-boot-transaction

Answer (score 3):

Please use @Primary annotation over the beans in either of the datasource configuration and it will work.

Example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"net.elyland.pipe.repositories.router"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "routerEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "routerTransactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"net.elyland.pipe.domain.router"})
public class RouterRepositoryConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "routerDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "router.datasource")
    public DataSource routerDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "routerPU")
    @Bean(name = "routerEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean routerEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("routerDataSource")DataSource routerDataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(routerDataSource)
                .properties(hibernateProperties())
                .packages(Ip.class, Net.class, Provider.class, QueueRule.class, QueueType.class,RemoteIp.class,Subnet.class,TrafficQueue.class)
                .persistenceUnit("routerPU")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "routerTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager mysqlTransactionManager(@Qualifier("routerEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    private Map hibernateProperties() {

        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("routerHibernate.properties");

        try {
            Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);

            return properties.entrySet().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            e -> e.getKey().toString(),
                            e -> e.getValue())
                    );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new HashMap();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @flyrock for your answer!
Can you explain why is necessary add the '@Primary' annotation in every bean? I got confused.
I was confused because my understanding was that '@Primary' annotation is necessary just in the EntityManagerFactoryBean.

Answer (score 0):

When having multiple data sources in spring-boot, use separate class for each data source to for the sake of readability of code as well as to avoid such errors (Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.)

In case of single datasource in Application, spring boot would have created a default entityManagerFactory bean for it. But on having multiple data sources we need to define entityManagerFactory & transactionManager explicitly for each of them.

For example, you have to use two data sources in your app ds1 & ds2, create beans like below :

**Bean for ds1**

```
@Configuration
@Import(SomePrimaryConfig.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.ds1.repos",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "ds1EMF", 
    transactionManagerRef = "ds1TM")
public class DataSource1 {

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("ds1.datasource")
public DataSource ds1DataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder<?> dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    // other datasource details to set
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
}

@Bean
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ds1EMF(DataSource ds1DataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(ds1DataSource);      
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.ds1.models");      
    //entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
JpaTransactionManager ds1TM(EntityManagerFactory ds1EMF) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(ds1EMF);
    return transactionManager;
 }
}
```

**Bean for ds2**

```
@Configuration
@Import(SomePrimaryConfig.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.ds2.repos",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "ds2EMF", 
    transactionManagerRef = "ds2TM")
public class DataSource2 {

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("ds2.datasource")
public DataSource ds1DataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder<?> dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    // other datasource details to set
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
}

@Bean
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ds2EMF(DataSource ds2DataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(ds2DataSource);      
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.ds2.models");      
    //entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
JpaTransactionManager ds2TM(EntityManagerFactory ds2EMF) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(ds2EMF);
    return transactionManager;
 }
}
```