# Error creating bean with name 'xxxEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application with hibernate. Spring boot 2.13, Java 11.

When I start the application, I get an exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xxxEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [fr/yyy/xx/config/DbConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/access/AccessType
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at fr.yyy.xxx.xxxliApplication.main(xxxApplication.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131) ~[idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/access/AccessType
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3167) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:3192) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1905) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.applyInjections(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:292) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:283) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:688) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:136) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:51) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.access.AccessType
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 41 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here's my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>fr.yyy</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea.flexy-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexy-hikaricp</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
            <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I've tried a lot of things : 
[Spring boot data jpa multiple datasources entityManagerFactory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975605/spring-boot-data-jpa-multiple-datasources-entitymanagerfactory-error)
[Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource : Invocation of init method failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058001/error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfactory-defined-in-class-path-resou)

**Edit :** 
My dependency tree :

```
[INFO] fr.yyy:xxx-backend:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:jar:3.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-core:jar:3.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.25.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.atteo:evo-inflector:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.14.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.6:compile (optional)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.11.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.10:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.2:test
[INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.vladmihalcea.flexy-pool:flexy-hikaricp:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.vladmihalcea.flexy-pool:flexy-pool-core:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.vladmihalcea.flexy-pool:flexy-dropwizard-metrics:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:4.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jmx:jar:4.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:jar:0.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- org.tuckey:urlrewritefilter:jar:4.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.23.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.4.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:5.3.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.6:compile
[INFO] \- org.ehcache:ehcache:jar:3.6.3:compile
```

**Edit2 :** 
When I run with mvn spring-boot:run, it's still an exception on creating bean xxxEntityManagerFactory but the problem seems to be with the cache Region factory :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xxxEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [fr/yyy/xxx/config/DbConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service
.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
        at fr.yyy.xxx.xxxApplication.main(xxxApplication.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:558) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Thank you very much
Clément

Comment: You have incompatible Hibernate dependencies, review `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you be more precise ? I have only hibernate-core. The only hibernate dependencies I see in my dependency tree are :
org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.14.Final
org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.7.Final
org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.4.Final
org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:5.3.7.Final

Comment: Reopened your question since you don't have problems with Hibernate dependencies, it's not the usual issue. Can you post `mvn dependency:tree` output?

Comment: I've just edited my post. Thank you

Comment: Does it fail with the same exception when you run `mvn spring-boot:run` from the command line? It feels like badly configured intellij project.

Comment: it's still an exception on creating bean xxxEntityManagerFactory but the problem seems to be with the cache Region factory. I've edited the post for the details.

Answer (score 1):

Your first exception is the result of miss-configured IntelliJ project. Reimport the Maven project to ensure that the IntelliJ setup is up to date. The IntelliJ runner behavior should be the same as `mvn spring-boot:run`.

The root cause is `hibernate-ehcache` 5.3.7.Final dependency which provides integration with Ehcache 2.X. As per [the dependency `pom.xml`](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-ehcache/5.3.7.Final/hibernate-ehcache-5.3.7.Final.pom):

> Integration for using Ehcache 2.x as a Hibernate second-level-cache provider

You are attempting to use it with Ehcache 3.X. This is not a supported setup, downgrade to Ehcache 2.X e.g.`net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.10.6` if you plan to use `hibernate-ehcache`.

Comment: Thank you. It's still the same problem when I run spring-boot:run. But when I start the application with Intelli, the exception has changed : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xxxEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [fr/yyy/xxx/config/DbConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/CacheDataDescription
So it seems I have the same behavior with Intellij and command line.

Comment: With hibernate-ehcache in my pom.xml, it uses net.sf.ehcache 2.10.6 automatically, but my error is : Unable to
resolve name [net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory] as strategy [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]: Unable to load class [net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory]: org/hibernate/cache/TimestampsRegion: org.hibernate.cache.T
imestampsRegion