# Read and Write datasources in one spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I want to have read and write datasources for replication purposes in spring boot app. Are there any examples on how to implement this behavior?

Comment: I want to have 2 separate data sources which I'll be able to use for different operation(read and write)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for http://fedulov.website/2015/10/14/dynamic-datasource-routing-with-spring/

Answer (score 0):

This could help you
[Spring Boot Configure and Use Two DataSources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources)

also you could take a look on this [blog](https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7)

Comment: I didn't find how I can choose between datasources for different methods.