# Spring boot JPA how to add multiple databases from same connection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I have two different mysql database from the same connection and would like to use both in my application.properties like this way:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/membership
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/finance
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

But this is not allowed (duplicate key's).
I have found [this guide](https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7) but this is to much code i think not a elegant solution, looks like workaround for simple problem.
Are there better and much simpler solutions?

PS: I am new to spring boot.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decleare different keys for different datasource. The main config for multi datasource is(this is the demo):

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.foo")
public DataSourceProperties fooDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.foo")
public DataSource fooDataSource() {
    return fooDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.bar")
public DataSourceProperties barDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.bar")
public DataSource barDataSource() {
    return barDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}
```

You can refer to [this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html) and [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources) to have an overview for the configuration.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use only 1 MySQL database. Try to combine with PostgreSQL. [Example](http://roufid.com/spring-boot-multiple-databases-configuration/)