# Spring Data, multiple datasources, Not a Managed Type exception

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, netsuite

I've been trying to get multiple database systems working within the same spring boot project for longer than it should take. I keep running into the following exception and need to have more eyes to nudge me towards the fix.

I apologize for the sheer volume of code below, however as I am unsure where the issue actually occurs I listed it all below.

One note: I am using a proprietary ERP's database as one of the endpoints. This endpoint is an Oracle database and is read only. If required we can switch that to a MySQL endpoint, however my use case requires the ERP's endpoint in order for the project to be successful.

Resources used:

- https://scattercode.co.uk/2016/01/05/multiple-databases-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-jpa/
- https://scattercode.co.uk/2013/11/18/spring-data-multiple-databases/
- http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases
- https://www.infoq.com/articles/Multiple-Databases-with-Spring-Boot
- https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7
- [Spring Boot Configure and Use Two DataSources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources)
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-two-datasources

I'm sure my answer may still reside in one of the above, however I'm too close to the problem now, which is where I need assistance.

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.xxx.ddbo.suiteanalytics.objects.ReturnsReasonBrand
```

Code:

```
application.properties

    #Global properties for spring configuration
    logging.level.org.apache=ERROR      
    logging.level.org.springframework=WARN
    logging.level.org.hibernate=INFO        
    logging.level.org.hibernate.type=INFO

    #Spring configuration
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES
    spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=info
    spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
    spring.jpa.database=default


    ## DATABASE CONFIGURATIONS

    #Properties for PostgreSQL connection
    spring.postgresql.datasource.url=xxxxxxxx
    spring.postgresql.datasource.username=xxxxxxxx
    spring.postgresql.datasource.password=xxxxxxxx
    spring.postgresql.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
    spring.postgresql.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50

    #Properties for NetSuite SuiteAnalytics ODBC connection
    #Sandbox URL
    spring.suiteanalytics.datasource.url=xxxxxxxx
    #Production URL
    #spring.suiteanalytics.datasource.url=xxxxxxxx
    spring.suiteanalytics.datasource.username=xxxxxxxx
    spring.suiteanalytics.datasource.password=xxxxxxxx
    spring.suiteanalytics.datasource.driver-class-name=com.netsuite.jdbc.openaccess.OpenAccessDriver
    spring.suiteanalytics.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50

DdboApplication.java (ddbo)

    @EnableJpaRepositories
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan("com.xxx.ddbo")
    public class DdboApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

        @Autowired
        private ReturnReasonsBrandRepository rrRepo;
        @Autowired
        private CustomListValuesRepository customListValuesRepository;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DdboApplication.class, args);
        }

        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

            CustomSegments cs = new CustomSegments(rrRepo);
            cs.printReturnReasonBrand();

            CustomLists cl = new CustomLists(customListValuesRepository);
            cl.printCustomListValues();
        }
    }

PostgresqlConfig.java (ddbo.postgresql.configuration)

    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaRepositories(
            basePackages = "com.xxx.ddbo.postgresql.interfaces",
            entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
            transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager"
    )
    public class PostgresqlConfig {


        @Primary
        @Bean(name = "dataSource")
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.postgresql")
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }

        @Primary
        @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
                EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {

            HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");

            return builder
                    .dataSource(dataSource)
                    .properties(properties)
                    .packages("com.xxx.ddbo.postgresql.interfaces")
                    .persistenceUnit("foo")
                    .build();
        }

        @Primary
        @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
                @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
        }
    }

CustomListValuesRepository.java (ddbo.postgresql.interfaces)

    @Repository
    public interface CustomListValuesRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomListValues,CustomListValuePkey>{
    }

CustomLists.java (ddbo.postgresql.logic)

    @Component
    public class CustomLists {

        private final CustomListValuesRepository customListValuesRepository;

        @Autowired
        public CustomLists(CustomListValuesRepository customListValuesRepository) {
            this.customListValuesRepository = customListValuesRepository;
        }

        public void printCustomListValues(){
            List<CustomListValues> values = customListValuesRepository.findAll();
            for(CustomListValues value: values){
                System.out.println(value.getValueText());
            }
        }
    }

CustomLists.java (ddbo.postgresql.objects)
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "custom_lists")
    public class CustomLists {

        @Id
        @Column
        private String listIntId;

        @Column
        private String mongoId;

        public CustomLists(String listIntId) {
            this.listIntId = listIntId;
        }

        public CustomLists() {
        }

        public String getListIntId() {
            return listIntId;
        }

        public void setListIntId(String listIntId) {
            this.listIntId = listIntId;
        }

        public String getMongoId() {
            return mongoId;
        }

        public void setMongoId(String mongoId) {
            this.mongoId = mongoId;
        }

    }   

CustomListValuePkey (ddbo.postgresql.objects)
    @Embeddable
    public class CustomListValuePkey implements Serializable {

        @Column
        private String listId;
        @Column
        private String valueIntId;

        public String getListId() {
            return listId;
        }

        public void setListId(String listId) {
            this.listId = listId;
        }

        public String getValueIntId() {
            return valueIntId;
        }

        public void setValueIntId(String valueIntId) {
            this.valueIntId = valueIntId;
        }
    }

CustomListValues.java (ddbo.postgresql.objects)
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "custom_list_values")
    public class CustomListValues implements Serializable {

        @EmbeddedId
        private CustomListValuePkey pkey;

        @Column
        private String valueText;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "listIntId")
        private CustomLists listId;


        public CustomLists getListId() {
            return listId;
        }

        public void setListId(CustomLists listId) {
            this.listId = listId;
        }

        public String getValueText() {
            return valueText;
        }

        public void setValueText(String valueText) {
            this.valueText = valueText;
        }

        public CustomListValuePkey getPkey() {
            return pkey;
        }

        public void setPkey(CustomListValuePkey pkey) {
            this.pkey = pkey;
        }
    }

SuiteAnalyticsConfig.java (ddbp.suiteanalytics.configuration)
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
    @EnableJpaRepositories(
            basePackages = "com.xxx.ddbo.suiteanalytics.interfaces",
            entityManagerFactoryRef = "suiteanalyticsEntityManagerFactory",
            transactionManagerRef = "suiteanalyticsTransactionManager"
    )
    public class SuiteAnalyticsConfig {

        @Bean(name = "nsDataSource")
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.suiteanalytics")
        public DataSource nsDataSource() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }

        @Bean(name = "nsEntityManagerFactory")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean nsEntityManagerFactory(
                EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                @Qualifier("nsDataSource") DataSource nsDataSource) {

            HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");

            return builder
                    .dataSource(nsDataSource)
                    .properties(properties)
                    .packages("com.xxx.ddbo.suiteanalytics.interfaces")
                    .persistenceUnit("ReturnReasonsBrand")
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean(name = "nsTransactionManager")
        public PlatformTransactionManager nsTransactionManager(
                @Qualifier("nsEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory nsEntityManagerFactory) {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(nsEntityManagerFactory);
        }
    }

ReturnReasonsBrandRepository.java (ddbo.suiteanalytics.interfaces)
    @Repository
    public interface ReturnReasonsBrandRepository extends JpaRepository<ReturnsReasonBrand,Integer> {
        // ReturnsReasonBrand findOneByRrBrandId(Integer id);
    }

CustomSegments.java (ddbo.suiteanalytics.logic)
    @Component
    public class CustomSegments {

        private final ReturnReasonsBrandRepository rrRepo;

        @Autowired
        public CustomSegments(ReturnReasonsBrandRepository rrRepo) {
            this.rrRepo = rrRepo;
        }

        public void printReturnReasonBrand(){
            List<ReturnsReasonBrand> brand = rrRepo.findAll();
            for(ReturnsReasonBrand rrBrand : brand){
                System.out.println(rrBrand.getRrBrandName());
            }
        }
    }

ReturnReasonsBrand.java (ddbo.suiteanalytics.objects)
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "rr_brand")
    public class ReturnsReasonBrand {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "RR_BRAND_ID")
        private Integer rrBrandId;
        @Column(name = "RR_BRAND_NAME")
        private String rrBrandName;

        public Integer getRrBrandId() {
            return rrBrandId;
        }

        public void setRrBrandId(Integer rrBrandId) {
            this.rrBrandId = rrBrandId;
        }

        public String getRrBrandName() {
            return rrBrandName;
        }

        public void setRrBrandName(String rrBrandName) {
            this.rrBrandName = rrBrandName;
        }
    }
```

Full stack trace:

```
   2018-03-14 09:53:17.773  INFO 14512 --- [           main] com.xxx.ddbo.DdboApplication             : Starting DdboApplication on xxx with PID xxx (started by roberth in xxx)
2018-03-14 09:53:17.775  INFO 14512 --- [           main] com.xxx.ddbo.DdboApplication             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-03-14 09:53:18.740  INFO 14512 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: CustomListValues
    ...]
2018-03-14 09:53:18.808  INFO 14512 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2018-03-14 09:53:18.809  INFO 14512 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-03-14 09:53:18.810  INFO 14512 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2018-03-14 09:53:18.848  INFO 14512 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-03-14 09:53:19.130  INFO 14512 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2018-03-14 09:53:19.365  INFO 14512 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2018-03-14 09:53:19.366  INFO 14512 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@3249a1ce
2018-03-14 09:53:19.503  WARN 14512 --- [           main] org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass          : HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): com.xxx.ddbo.postgresql.objects.CustomListValuePkey
2018-03-14 09:53:19.503  WARN 14512 --- [           main] org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass          : HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): com.xxx.ddbo.postgresql.objects.CustomListValuePkey
2018-03-14 09:53:19.698  INFO 14512 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: ReturnReasonsBrand
    ...]
2018-03-14 09:53:35.120  INFO 14512 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
2018-03-14 09:53:36.268  INFO 14512 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
2018-03-14 09:53:36.434  WARN 14512 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ddboApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rrRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'returnReasonsBrandRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.xxx.ddbo.suiteanalytics.objects.ReturnsReasonBrand
2018-03-14 09:53:41.730 ERROR 14512 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ddboApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rrRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'returnReasonsBrandRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.xxx.ddbo.suiteanalytics.objects.ReturnsReasonBrand
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at com.xxx.ddbo.DdboApplication.main(DdboApplication.java:26) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'returnReasonsBrandRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.xxx.ddbo.suiteanalytics.objects.ReturnsReasonBrand
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.xxx.ddbo.suiteanalytics.objects.ReturnsReasonBrand
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:70) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:68) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:173) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:106) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:198) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Comment: First thing I can see is that your `entityManagerFactoryRef` and `transactionManagerRef` values on `SuiteAnalyticsConfig` don't actually match the bean names you're creating.

Comment: @Strelok Thanks for that catch - I changed both refs to use the ns prefix rather than Suiteanalytics. No dice unfortunately.

Comment: You should post the full stack trace

Comment: @Strelok added.

Answer (score 5):

`entityManagerFactory -> packages` should point to the package of your managed entities. Here you are pointing to `com.xxx.ddbo.suiteanalytics.interfaces` instead of `com.xxx.ddbo.suiteanalytics.objects` which contains all the entities to be managed by the entity manager. Update the package name in `nsEntityManagerFactory` in `SuiteAnalyticsConfig`.

```
return builder
              .dataSource(dataSource)
              .properties(properties)
              .packages("com.xxx.ddbo.suiteanalytics.objects")
              .persistenceUnit("foo")
              .build();
```

Make sure you also update the package name for `entityManagerFactory` in `PostgresqlConfig` to `ddbo.postgresql.objects` package

The configuration properties for the datasources should also have **datasource** as per the config file, e.g.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.postgresql.datasource")
```

Remove the `@EnableJpaRepositories` from `DdboApplication`.

The package structure needs to be fixed or the ComponentScan needs to be updated to find the spring components.

[Here](https://github.com/GSSwain/springboot-multi-datasource) is a repo which shows this in action.

Comment: If this is your updated code, then you are still having **com.xxx.ddbo.suiteanalytics.interfaces** this instead of **com.xxx.ddbo.suiteanalytics.objects**  inside nsEntityManagerFactory -> builder -> packages

Comment: I didn't update the code in the question - I just made the alterations to point to objects locally as well as corrected the factory and transaction references

Comment: `Get Field rrRepo in com.cwd.ddbo.DdboApplication required a bean of type 'com.cwd.ddbo.suiteanalytics.interfaces.ReturnReasonsBrandRepository' that could not be found.` once I removed @EnabledJpaRepositories from DdboApplication

Comment: I've also removed the config file as being part of the issue by specifying the url, user, pass and driver class through the DataSourceBuilder located in the dataSource method for both Postgres and SuiteAnalytics: 

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .url("jdbc:postgresql:xxxxxx")
                .username("xxxx")
                .password("xxxx")
                .driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
                .build();
    }

Comment: Fixed the issue with your repo. Specifically the issue was my basePackages annotation on the config class was pointing to objects not interfaces, coupled with DdboApplication having the EnableJpaRepositories annotation. If you can update your answer to include those details I'll gladly accept. Thanks for the help!