# How to connect to two different MySQL databases in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to connect two different MySQL databases with spring boot application. I want application to be able to communicate with both databases at the same time.

Comment: Just have two datasources and communicate with the correct database when you need to interact with it? There are numerous articles about this subject. Please do some research first. That is a part of your job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources

Answer (score 1):

You have to decleare different keys for different datasource.

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("mysql.connection1")
public DataSourceProperties connectionProp1() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("mysql.connection1")
public DataSource connection1() {
    return connectionProp1().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("mysql.connection2")
public DataSourceProperties connectionProp2() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("mysql.connection2")
public DataSource connection2() {
    return connectionProp2().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}
```