# Multiple DataSource is referring only one database in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, datasource, jdbctemplate

In my application i need to integrate two datasource but when i integrate the second database using JdbcTemplate then the previous one not working, instead all table created in the second datasource

**#1 DataSource**

```
@Configuration
@Profile("mariadb4j")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class EmbeddedMariaDBConfig {
private static final Logger L = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmbeddedMariaDBConfig.class);
private static final String DB_SERVICE = "dbServiceBean";

@Bean(name = {DB_SERVICE})
MariaDB4jSpringService mariaDB4jSpringService() {
    L.info("Initializing MariaDB4j service");
    return new MariaDB4jSpringService();
}

@Bean(name = "adminDataSource")
@Primary
@DependsOn(DB_SERVICE)
DataSource dataSource(MariaDB4jSpringService mdb, DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) throws ManagedProcessException {
    String dbName = dataSourceProperties.getName();
    L.debug("Embedded MariaDB datasource properties from spring: [{}]", dataSourceProperties);
    mdb.getDB().createDB(dbName);

    if(L.isDebugEnabled()) {
        DBConfigurationBuilder ecfg = mdb.getConfiguration();
        L.debug("JDBC URL for embedded MariaDB as reported by driver: [{}]", ecfg.getURL(dbName));
        L.debug("JDBC URL from spring config: [{}]", dataSourceProperties.getUrl());
        L.debug("JDBC Username: [{}]", dataSourceProperties.getUsername());
        L.debug("JDBC Password: [{}]", dataSourceProperties.getPassword());
    }

    return DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .username(dataSourceProperties.getUsername())
            .password(dataSourceProperties.getPassword())
            .url(dataSourceProperties.getUrl())
            .driverClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())
            .build();
  }
}
```

**Yaml Configuration**

```
spring:
  profiles: mariadb4j
  datasource:
   username: root
   password: password
   driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/t1
mariaDB4j:
 dataDir: /tmp/mariadb
 port: 3900
```

**2 DataSource**

```
@Configuration
public class ExoDBConfig {

@Bean(name="user")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/t2");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("user")DataSource dataSource) 
 {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
 }
}
```

When i use only one DataSource the 1st one then it's working fine and tables are creating in **t1** database but when i integrate the 2nd DataSource then it points to second DataSource means all the tables is creating in the **t2** database.

Comment: Did you check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources? That worked for me. You basically have to build up noth EntityManagers manually and define which package contains the entities for source1 and which for source2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Create DataSource object in the JdbcTemplate  itself, working for me, and you can create separate properties file for **t2** database

```
    @Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/t2");
    dataSource.setUsername("user");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```