# Create table on secondary db in spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I have two dbs to work with in spring boot.Connections have been established but schema.sql for db2 fails while initialization and is executing for db1 instead of db2. Below is the application.properties on my project. 
 I followed this example https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

Could someone help me with this ?

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://host:port/db
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

h2.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
h2.datasource.username=sa
h2.datasource.password=
h2.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

h2.datasource.data=schema-h2.sql
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
h2.datasource.initialize=true
h2.datasource.platform=h2
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Below are the config files for the databases :

MySqlDbConfig.java

```
   @Configuration
   @EnableTransactionManagement
   @EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
    basePackages = {"com.repository.mysql"})
   public class MySqlDbConfig { 
     @Primary
     @Bean(name = "dataSource")
     @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
     public DataSource dataSource() {
       return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
     }

     @Primary
     @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
     public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
          EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.domain.mysql").persistenceUnit("mqsql")
            .build();
      }

      @Primary
      @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
      public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
          @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
      }


}
```

H2DbConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "h2EntityManagerFactory",
transactionManagerRef = "h2TransactionManager", 
basePackages = {"com.repository.h2"})
public class H2DbConfig {

      @Bean(name = "h2DataSource")
      @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "h2.datasource")
      public DataSource h2DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
      }

      @Bean(name = "h2EntityManagerFactory")
      public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean h2EntityManagerFactory(
          EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("h2DataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.domain.h2").persistenceUnit("h2")
            .build();
      }

      @Bean(name = "h2TransactionManager")
      public PlatformTransactionManager h2TransactionManager(
          @Qualifier("h2EntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory h2EntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(h2EntityManagerFactory);
      }

}
```

Below is the stack trace

```
2018-07-16 12:19:17.771  INFO 13056 --- [           main] rmationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl : HHH000262: Table not found: hibernate_sequence
2018-07-16 12:19:17.786  INFO 13056 --- [           main] rmationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl : HHH000262: Table not found: hibernate_sequence
2018-07-16 12:19:17.818  WARN 13056 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/MySqlDbConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: mqsql] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2018-07-16 12:19:17.818  INFO 13056 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'h2'
2018-07-16 12:19:17.833  WARN 13056 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available)
2018-07-16 12:19:17.849 ERROR 13056 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/MySqlDbConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: mqsql] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at com.MonitorApplication.main(MonitorApplication.java:36) [bin/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: mqsql] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint)]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:420) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.createTable(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: CREATE command denied to user 'cds_hacp_support'@'10.233.65.78' for table 'hibernate_sequence'
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1540) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2595) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1468) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

Comment: can you provide your source code or any other details or exceptions

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30337582/4636715) you go for a look. And please share your code of bean declarations and the detailed stack trace, please.

Comment: @xXxpRoGrAmmErxXx , added the source code and error stack trace@ vahdet added the source code and error stack trace

Comment: @vahdet the example provided only shows how to connect to dbs, which is working for me already. I am trying to create a table in db2 (which is h2 in this case) during initialization, which is failing

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Moved the @primary  annotation to h2config and removed the extra app properties. Working as expected.