# How to provide data source entry in spring annotation based project.

Tags: java, spring, annotations, datasource

I am using spring 3 but my configuration is xml based in which I am trying to convert my project into annotation based using @configuration annotation.

I am little confused how to add data source entry as @Bean for two below cases

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/myds" />
</bean> 

<bean id="data_source" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
  <property name="url" value="url1" />
  <property name="username" value="user1" />
  <property name="password" value="****" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot Configure and Use Two DataSources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources)