# is it possible to connect to two databases one with spring jpa and another with spring jdbc

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I have a requirement to connect to two databases using spring boot. I can able to connect to two different databases using spring jpa, but I want to connect two databases one with spring jpa and another with spring jdbc

Comment: Yes. What do you need to know?

Comment: I want to know how to configure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot Configure and Use Two DataSources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I missed to add ComponentScan for JDBC connection configuration and removed @Primary annotation