# How to have different Hikari configurations for different datasources in spring-boot?

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

I want to have different parameter configurations like this:

```
spring:
   cassandra-datasource:
      hikari:
         poolName: CassandraHikari
         auto-commit: false
         maximumPoolSize: 500
spring:
   mysql-datasource:
      hikari:
         poolName: MySqlHikari
         auto-commit: false
         maximumPoolSize: 20
spring:
   sql-datasource:
      hikari:
         poolName: SqlHikari
         auto-commit: false
         maximumPoolSize: 50
```

How to use those different configurations?

Comment: did you try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30337582/1480381)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have configured two different databases without any problem. The problem here is with HIKARI, I want to have, for example, different maximumPoolSize for each one.