# Dynamically inject beans without annotations

Tags: spring-boot, spring-bean, spring-context

I want to generate objects based on the yaml file and inject it into the Spring container (like instantiating multiple DataSourceTransactionManager). The @Bean annotation does not meet the requirements. I can't get the configuration information to implement ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar because he needs a parameterless constructor. What should I do?

```
    @Bean("aaaTransactionManager")
public DataSourceTransactionManager get (    @Autowired @Qualifier("aaaDataSource")DataSource build){
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(build);
}
@Bean("cccTransactionManager")
public DataSourceTransactionManager get2 (    @Autowired @Qualifier("cccDataSource")DataSource build){
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(build);
}
```

How do I dynamically generate the above DataSourceTransactionManager, don't care about the number

Comment: Hi @munan, welcome to Stackoverflow. Can this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources help solve your problem?

Comment: Hi @artfulbeest ,These examples are correct, but not very useful to me. Because I am not sure how many datasources there are, so I may not be able to use Bean Annotation

Comment: So your need is to create datasources dynamically, which might not be know at build time?

Comment: Yes,maybe I need to implement ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar or BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor,what do you think?

Comment: But you need to know the datasource before using it, meaning datasources should be known at build time..only configurations can change. What is your use case for dynamic datasource?

Comment: A starter for mybatis. I try to implement ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar  like this .https://github.com/munan56/mutidata-boot-mybatis Now the headache is configuration convert to  Java Bean。 