# DataSourceBuilder does not pickup ConfigurationProperties(prefix="...")

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

My application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=${env.H2_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${env.H2_PASS}

spring.token-datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${env.MYSQL_HOST}/${env.MYSQL_DB}
spring.token-datasource.username=${env.MYSQL_USER}
spring.token-datasource.password=${env.MYSQL_PASS}
```

My Configuration.java code snippet

```java
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource regularDataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.token-datasource")
    public DataSource tokenDataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

However, if I put a break point at each of `return dataSource;`, I see the DataSource object not populated with the correponding property values, e.g. jdbcUrl would be `null`.

[image]

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Followed https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.2/reference/html/howto.html#howto-two-datasources and crafted following code which works:

```java
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties regularDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.configuration")
    public HikariDataSource regularDataSource() {
        HikariDataSource dataSource = regularDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.token-datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties tokenDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.token-datasource.configuration")
    public DataSource tokenDataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = tokenDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

It's interesting that the original code snippet does NOT work, while it's still the approach recommened by many Java tutorials and stackoverflow posts. For example,

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases
- [Spring Boot Configure and Use Two DataSources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources/30344608#30344608)

Comment: It's really weird. With Spring Boot 3, `spring.datasource-some` doesn't work while `app.datasource-some` works.