# Transaction Management across two data sources (ChainedTransactionManager) - SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-transactions

Why Spring `ChainedTransactionManager` is deprecated? Does Spring provide any alternative lib to support multiple transaction managers?

My use-case:- We are building a Spring Boot application that is connected to two data sources let's say (db1 and db2), which performs insert operation on both databases (db1 and db2). And our requirement is something like this :
insert -> DB1 -> SUCCESSFUL
insert -> DB2 -> ERROR
ROLLBACK DB1

Currently, we are using `ChaninedTransactionManager` and it is working as expected, but I can see that lib is deprecated. So, just wanted to make sure is it safe to use that, or does Spring provide any alternate lib that we can use as a replacement for this?

Comment: I hope this work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74884169/6456107 Kind regards

Comment: I hope this sample in this answer works for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74884169/6456107

Comment: I hope this answer here can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74884169/6456107

Answer (score 10):

### ChainedTransactionManager

> The configured instances will start transactions in the order given and commit/rollback in reverse order, which means the PlatformTransactionManager most likely to break the transaction should be the last in the list configured.

If you chained transactions in this order : transaction1, transaction2

```
transaction1 begin
  transaction2 begin
  transaction2 commit -> error rollbacks, rollbacks transction1 too
transaction1 commit -> error, only rollbacks transaction1
```

The case `insert -> DB1 -> SUCCESSFUL insert -> DB2 -> ERROR ROLLBACK DB1` is working.

**But**, if you had `insert -> DB1 -> FAIL ROLLBAK DB1 -> DB2 -> SUCCESSFUL`, the insert is commited for DB2 and not for DB1. More details in [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/most-common-spring-transactional-mistakes).

If your are OK with this, you can copy the class in your project et keep using it : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/issues/2232#issuecomment-1018473289

### JtaTransactionManager with Atomikos

To have all transactions rollback if one fails, I changed my conf to use JtaTransactionManager (with spring boot and posgtres).

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**application.properties**

```
my.datasource.one.unique-resource-name=
my.datasource.one.xa-properties.url=jdbc:postgresql://
my.datasource.one.xa-data-source-class-name=org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource
my.datasource.one.xa-properties.user=
my.datasource.one.xa-properties.password=
my.datasource.one.max-pool-size=
my.datasource.one.min-pool-size=

my.datasource.two.unique-resource-name=
my.datasource.two.xa-properties.url=jdbc:postgresql://
my.datasource.two.xa-data-source-class-name=org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource
my.datasource.two.xa-properties.user=
my.datasource.two.xa-properties.password=
my.datasource.two.max-pool-size=
my.datasource.two.min-pool-size=
```

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("my.datasource.one")
    public DataSource dataSourceOne() {
        return new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
    }

    @Bean("entityManagerOne")
    @DependsOn("transactionManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerOne(@Autowired JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.default_schema", "public");
        properties.put("hibernate.ddl-auto", "none");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setJtaDataSource(dataSourceOne());
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan("");
        entityManager.setPersistenceUnitName("");
        entityManager.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return entityManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("my.datasource.two")
    public DataSource dataSourceTwo() {
        return new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
    }

    @Bean("entityManagerTwo")
    @DependsOn("transactionManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerTwo(@Autowired JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.default_schema", "public");
        properties.put("hibernate.ddl-auto", "none");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setJtaDataSource(dataSourceTwo());
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan("");
        entityManager.setPersistenceUnitName("");
        entityManager.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return entityManager;
    }
```

**jta.properties**

```
com.atomikos.icatch.enable_logging=false
com.atomikos.icatch.default_jta_timeout=60000000
com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout=100000000
com.atomikos.icatch.threaded_2pc=true
```

```
    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(@Autowired Environment env) {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserTransaction userTransaction() throws SystemException {
        var userTransaction = new UserTransactionImp();
        userTransaction.setTransactionTimeout(60000);
        return userTransaction;
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionManager atomikosTransactionManager() throws SystemException {
        var userTransactionManager = new UserTransactionManager();
        userTransactionManager.setForceShutdown(true);
        return userTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Autowired UserTransaction userTransaction, @Autowired TransactionManager atomikosTransactionManager) throws Throwable {
        return new JtaTransactionManager(userTransaction, atomikosTransactionManager);
    }
```

Enable prepared transactions for postgres

**postgresql.conf**

```
max_prepared_transactions = 100     # zero disables the feature
```

Sources that helped me to get this :

https://www.baeldung.com/java-atomikos

http://www.thedevpiece.com/configuring-multiple-datasources-using-springboot-and-atomikos/

https://github.com/YihuaWanglv/spring-boot-jta-atomikos-sample

Comment: Great answer, including references!
Thank you very much for sharing

Answer (score 1):

Because there is an API improvement. From the docs
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/transaction/ChainedTransactionManager.html

> Instead of using ChainedTransactionManager for attaching callbacks to transaction commit (pre commit/post commit), either register a TransactionSynchronization to explicitly follow transaction cleanup with simplified semantics in case of exceptions.

You are free to still use it, just keep in mind that at some point in the time that class will be removed in future versions of Spring and upgrading will not be possible without refactoring of that part.

Comment: Yes, but there isn't a practical example of how you would use a TransactionSynchronization to achieve multiple datasource commits...

Comment: It's not actually an improvement, please note that they deprecated all the features of transaction chaining, thus `TransactionSynchronization ` is not a replacement. please refer to this [ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/issues/2232)