# How to configure two databases (local and remote both) in a Spring Boot JDBC application and insert data into table

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, amazon-rds

I am new to Spring Boot and trying to configure and access two databases using Spring JDBC. Can someone help me here? I have one local database (MySQL) and another on AWS RDS (MySQL). I have configured `application.yml` with two data sources, but whenever I run the application, it only connects to the last database configured in `application.yml`. I want to connect to both database as from one database I need to get information and process and put logs in AWS RDS. Can someone help me here?

This is my Dbconfig file

```
@Bean(name = "rdsDatasource")
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.rds")
public DataSource rdsDatasource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
public NamedParameterJdbcOperations namedParameterJdbcOperations(@Qualifier("rdsDatasource") DataSource rdsDbDataSource) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(rdsDbDataSource);
}
```

application.yml

```yaml
datasource:
  local:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    username: test
    password: test
    port: 3306
  rds:
    url: jdbc:mysql://aws-rds/test
    username: test
    password: test
    port: 3306.
```

Comment: Wellcome! you can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources

Answer (score 1):

You've configured your DataSource to use the properties for the RDS database, that's what `@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.rds")` does.

Each DataSource object can only connect to one database. You should create another DataSource object with `@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.local")` and name it something else like `@Bean("localDatasource")`, then you will have two different DataSource objects with connections to your two databases.

Comment: I do not want to use localDataSource in same class/ package.. I m using it in different module/functionality/package.. how to do that ... lets say I have project which has 2 packages A and B ...inside package A all task is done using local Db and inside package B all tasks uses rds Db.. any idea how to go about that ?