# Connect to both ActiveMQ and IBM MQ

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am using the following Maven dependency and class in my Spring Boot application to send messages to ActiveMQ:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@EnableJms
public class MQSender {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public void sendMsgActiveMQ(String msg) {
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("DEV.QUEUE1", msg);
    }
    
/*    public void sendMsgIBMMQ(String msg) {
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("DEV.QUEUE1", msg);
    }*/
    
}
```

How could I use the same class or any other class within the same application to send messages to IBM MQ as well? If I add the add the below dependency how will the `@Autowired` `JmsTemplate` behave?

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
   <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I think it is the same as when you have multiple databases (for example). You have to define "@Bean" with a "@Qualifier" and inject one or the other as needed. Example for datasources: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources

Answer (score 1):

You can get the IBM MQ client jars file with Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

As to your `@Autowired` question, your problem is ambiguity by type.  You will need JMS connections factories for the two brokers that have the same type.  The article [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire) has some good suggestions.

I prefer to only `@Autowire` in test cases, where the application context is small.  For a practical application, I prefer explicit initialization.  (maybe I'm just used to it).  In any event, have a look here [github](https://github.com/grovedc/CamelSpringJMS) for some examples that may have be useful.