# How to test a repository with a user that have update rights and the test needs tot add records to the database

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa, junit5

I use mysql and spring 5, spring-data-jpa and spring-boot and JUnit5.

This must be a common problem but I don't see te sollution.
I have to test a repository with a user that has only Update rights in the databse,
but to perform the test I hava a sql script to inbject re number of record to perform my test on.
How do i add record to the database (mysql) with a user that has create rights an perform my repository tests with a user that has only update rights.

Kind Greetings,
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define two different datasources for the same database: one using the update-rights user, and the other using the create-rights user.

In order to do so, you can take a look at: [Spring Boot Configure and Use Two DataSources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources)

and also to: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Once you have defined both datasources, with their corresponding transaction managers, then you can specify which transaction manager / datasource applies within the @Transaction annotation configuration (previous reference shows an example with JUnit tests).

By other hand, if you don't mind having a custom simplified database environment for executing junit tests, it would be easier to configure a spring profile with an in-memory database like H2, in which you could use the same user for everything. Anyway, this is a simplication of the database environment, and would miss testing your code on database fine-grained permissions (as I assume that is one of your goals).