# Login Access from 2 different mysql table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, spring-data

Can anyone help me configuring my Spring boot web app to access or have login from 2 different MySQL tables?

App should login access from 2 different MySQL tables(users and admins).
Upon login, they should be redirected to their respective dashboards.

For now, I am able to configure my web app to access user details from users table, unable to access admin table for login.

Comment: it's going to be your help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources

Comment: Really appreciate your effort. However I have only 1 database.
Just the tables are different. User and Admin table.

I got the solution of using 2 security config files, with annotation of order (1) & (2) will that be ok?

Comment: for example, do you want to use the same entity by two accounts?

Comment: No. I have 2 different entities, User and Admin.
both will have 2 different login pages.
/userlogin and /adminlogin