# How to access two different user of same db in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an application that runs Spring MVC.

I need it to access 2 different User of same DB in my app.

How do I configure this using application.properties file?

> application.properties file

```
jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@myoracle.db.server:1521:my_sid
jdbc.username=USERA
jdbc.password=passwrord1

jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@myoracle.db.server:1521:my_sid
jdbc.username=USERB
jdbc.password=passwrord2
```

Regards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot configure and use two data sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-data-sources)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating more than one data source works same as creating the first one. You might want to mark one of them as @Primary if you are using the default auto-configuration for JDBC or JPA (then that one will be picked up by any @Autowired injections).

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.primary")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.secondary")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```