# Spring Boot Two Databases Configuration

Tags: spring, mongodb, postgresql, spring-boot

I am trying to configure my Spring app to use a local postgresql database for my customer entity, and remote mongodb atlas cluster for my post documents.

I would obviously have to overide some spring boot config, but would I am unsure how to do this.

Would I configure this with application.properties or an @Configuration class? Would I use both?

Is there even any difference between Spring annotation config and application.properties config?

Also, how would I go about doing normal orm mappings from a user to a post once this is set up?

@Entity  Customer(id, name, Set)
@Document  Post(id, title, customer_id)

Can I still use @OneToMany and @ManyToOne hibernate annotations?

Comment: Here is exactly what you need : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30344608/14805530

Comment: try https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-multiple-datasources