# Connecting to data source without specifying database name

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring boot and database mongo. Our database is placed on AWS cluster. Inside data source we have couples databases(AccountsDB, SubscriptionsDB etc). I did realization, when in Spring boot I connected to 2 databases using disable autoconfiguration in application.properties file and connect to mongoDB twice: ones, to database AccountsDB(

```
mongodb://${MONGO_DB_USERNAME}:${MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}@${MONGODB_HOST}:${MONGODB_PORT}/{AccountsDB}?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false
```

), and second connection to SubscriptionDB(

```
mongodb://${MONGO_DB_USERNAME}:${MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}@${MONGODB_HOST}:${MONGODB_PORT}/{SubscriptionDB}?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false
```

).
But my manager unhappy with this realization... There is any way to connect to data source without clarification of data base name? I couldn't find any solution for this, if we are not clarify its not showing any data. Thank you for any replying

I tried to connect without clarification, and it doesn't display any data

```
mongodb://${MONGO_DB_USERNAME}:${MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}@${MONGODB_HOST}:${MONGODB_PORT}/?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false
```

Might be any way to connect to datasource and after using SpringJPA make connection?

Comment: checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48140893/3651739 ,

Comment: You can skip the database name, however then it defaults to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470