# Primary and Secondary datasource using jakarta instead of javax

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-17

After upgrading to Java 17 and Spring Boot 3.0.1, jakarta is also replacing javax. You can add as many datasources as you like, as long as they share the same username/password and driveClassName.  However, what if you have two datasources with different creds?  There doesn't seem to be an equivalent to how javax handles this. i.e., see first answer here with the Config class...
[Spring Boot configure and use two data sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-data-sources)

What is the jakarta equivalent or how do we configure this?