How to configure a DB on Spring Data JPA where its credentials are mapped on another entity (on other DB)?
Use case
I have some customers each customer runs its own backend instance which is connected to its own database, each backend instance has its database, but the credentials used to connect to those databases (primary database) are all the same and those credentials are in another database regardless backend instance, my point is to configure a database connection on Spring Data Jpa which its credentials depends from another database (they are present on a mapped entity for this DB) , then I created an Entity containing database credentials (and other infos):
@Data
public class Assinante {
    @Id
    @Column(name="cnpj_da_base")
    private String cnpj;
    @Column(name="db_jdbc_url")
    private String databaseURL;
    @Column(name="db_user")
    private String databaseUser;
    @Column(name="db_password")
    private String databasePassword;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Categoria classificacao;
    @Column(name="token_varejo")
    private String tokenVarejo;
    @Column(name="api_url")
    private String apiUrl;
    @Column(name="proxy_url")
    private String proxyUrl;
    @Column(name="proxy_https_port")
    private Integer proxyHttpsPort;
    @Column(name="proxy_login")
    private String proxyLogin;
    @Column(name="proxy_pass")
    private String proxyPass;
    @Column(name="valido_ate")
    private LocalDate validoAte;
}


I need a way to set the primary database source based on the credentials in this entity, then I did:
For primary database:
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "org.crm", // Adjusted package for primary repositories
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "mainEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "mainTransactionManager",
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(
                type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {
                AssinanteRepository.class
        }
        )
)
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Value("{app.assinante-cnpj}")
    private String cnpj;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private HikariConfig hikariConfig;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        SimpleJpaRepository assinanteRepository = new SimpleJpaRepository<Assinante, String>(Assinante.class, entityManager);
        Optional<Assinante> assinante = assinanteRepository.findById(cnpj);
        if (assinante.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("CNPJ NÃO ASSINADO");
        }
        // Configurações do Hikari baseadas no assinante
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(assinante.get().getDatabaseURL());
        hikariConfig.setUsername(assinante.get().getDatabaseUser());
        hikariConfig.setPassword(assinante.get().getDatabasePassword());

        // Supondo que você tenha outras propriedades no objeto Assinante
        hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        hikariConfig.setValidationTimeout(3000);
        hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(60000);
        hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(1800000);
        hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(5);
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(20);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mainEntityManagerFactory() throws Exception {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("org.crm"); // Main packages to scan
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy");
        properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", "org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy");
        factory.setJpaProperties(properties);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager mainTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory mainEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(mainEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}

For database containing the credentials:
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "org.crm.domain.entidadesBusiness.assinantesSistema", // Pacote onde está o repositório do Assinante
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "assinanteEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "assinanteTransactionManager"
)
public class AssinanteDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource assinanteDataSource() {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("secret");
        hikariConfig.setUsername("secret");
        hikariConfig.setPassword("secret");

        // Configurações do HikariCP
        hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        hikariConfig.setValidationTimeout(3000);
        hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(60000);
        hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(1800000);
        hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(5);
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(20);

        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean assinanteEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(assinanteDataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(Assinante.class.getPackageName());
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy");
        properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", "org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy");
        factory.setJpaProperties(properties);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager assinanteTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory assinanteEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(assinanteEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}



the problem is when I ran the application I got circular dependency between EntityManager and DataSource

Saving database credentials (password) in a database table without any sort of encryption is a really terrible idea. Please make sure you don't do this. If this database gets compromised, you are also compromising anything that is saved there.
Also this part of your statement is not clear "but this database credentials (primary database) are in another database regardless backend instance". It might be the case that you are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30344608/460557 which is to have multiple datasources configured in your application.

@JorgeCampos I edited it, my objective is to configure a database connection based on an entity of another database.

I solved it by moving the annotation @Primary to the database containing the credentials
