# mysql query returning same result on two different query

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have written a method in Java and It returns list according to query.  By mistake I wrote allotment_date to allotmentDate but it returns same list  after correcting it and in mysql table fields name also allotment_date. I don't understand why allotment_date returning same list.

```
public List<ShareAllotment> getlis(STUDENT st, Date fromAllotDate, Date toAllotDate, Integer branch_code) {
        Session session = getSessionFactory(st).openSession();
        try {
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class);
            if (fromAllotDate != null) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("allotment_date", fromAllotDate));
            }
            if (toAllotDate != null) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.le("allotment_date", toAllotDate));
            }
            if(branch_code != null && branch_code > 0) 
                criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("branch_code", branch_code));
            return criteria.list();

        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }

public List<ShareAllotment> getlis(STUDENT st, Date fromAllotDate, Date toAllotDate, Integer branch_code) {
        Session session = getSessionFactory(st).openSession();
        try {
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class);
            if (fromAllotDate != null) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("allotmentDate", fromAllotDate));
            }
            if (toAllotDate != null) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.le("allotmentDate", toAllotDate));
            }
            if(branch_code != null && branch_code > 0) 
                criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("branchCode", branch_code));
            return criteria.list();

        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Student POGO is

```
@Entity(name = "student")
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student extends BaseDO{

    public Student() {
    }

    @Column(name = "application_date")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy")
    @NotNull(message="Please enter Application Date")
    private Date applicationDate;

    @Column(name = "receipt_date")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy")
    @NotNull(message="Please enter Date of Receipt")
    private Date dateofReceipt;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy")
    @NotNull(message="Please enter Allotment Date")
    @Column(name = "allotment_date")
    private Date allotmentDate;

    @Column(name = "branch_code")
    private Integer branchCode;

    public void setApplicationDate(Date applicationDate) {
        this.applicationDate = applicationDate;
    }

    public Date getAllotmentDate() {
        return allotmentDate;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getAllotmentDateStr() {
        return allotmentDate != null ? Configuration.DATE_FORMAT.format(allotmentDate): "";
    }

    @Transient
    public String getAllotDateShotStr() {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy"); 
        return allotmentDate != null ? df.format(allotmentDate): "";
    }

    public void setAllotmentDate(Date allotmentDate) {
        this.allotmentDate = allotmentDate;
    }

    public Integer getBranchCode() {
        return branchCode;
    }

    public void setBranchCode(Integer branchCode) {
        this.branchCode = branchCode;
    }

}
```

please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe the values that you pass in are null `if (fromAllotDate != null) {` and so that portion of code is not included

Comment: @ScaryWombat i have pass all the values and already checked it

Comment: do both methods produce the same query?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer one query values are on inspect is [allotment_date>=Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 IST 2017, allotment_date<=Fri Jun 30 00:00:00 IST 2017, branch_code=17]  and another query values are 
 [allotmentDate>=Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 IST 2017, allotmentDate<=Fri Jun 30 00:00:00 IST 2017, branchCode=17]

Comment: i was not asking for the values... show the queries

Comment: it is the hibernate naming convention see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681386/hibernate-entity-fields-camelcase-database-underscore

Comment: @XtremeBaumer on debuging i dont find out the query.

Comment: check the table maybe you have both columns (fields) ?

Comment: @Yazan i have already checked. there is only one column with name is allotment_date

Comment: @Ravindra Please paste Student class source code, but i only see 2 options:
either your fromAllotDate  and toAllotDate variables are null and corresponding code is not executed or you have a  in your Student class  the two attributes (allotmentDate & allotment_date) mapped on the same column

Comment: @Ravindra OK so the property name is allotmentDate and it is the one that should be used in criteria, so now run your code in debug mode with `allotment_date` and confirm that this portion of code `criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("allotment_date", fromAllotDate));` is executed, if it is, so you should encounter exception since allotmend_date doen't exists as property name. (I suppose in your BaseDo class you don't have any mapping on allotment_date)

Comment: @AbassA my BaseDO is   
public abstract class BaseDO {
 protected boolean allBorders= false;
 protected boolean topBorder= false;
 protected boolean topBottomBorders= false;
 protected boolean leftRightBorders= false;
 protected int color=0;
 public boolean isTopBorder() {
  return topBorder;
 }

 public void setTopBorder(boolean topBorder) {
  this.topBorder = topBorder;
 }

 public boolean getTopBottomBorders() {
  return topBottomBorders;
 }
 public boolean getAllBorders() {
  return allBorders;
 }
public int getColor() {
  return color;
 }
}

Comment: @Ravindra ok fine , please dont put code in comment section it's unreadable, instead update your post. Have you launched  your code in debubg mode ? what is the result ?

Comment: yes, same result.