# Hibernate mapping camelCase field to snake_case

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am using hibernate with postgresql. I am curious if is it possible to map for example this entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

}
```

in database I have columns like first_name, last_name. I got error that I introduce wrong names (when I add for example `@Column(name = "first_name")`; everything is ok. How can I avoid adding `@Column` neither change database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map Hibernate entity fields using camelCase to snake\_case (underscore) database identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681386/how-to-map-hibernate-entity-fields-using-camelcase-to-snake-case-underscore-da)

Comment: That's weird because this is the default in Spring Data JPA to convert camel to snake case. Did you configure something?

Comment: It was working in that way, after I used DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl with creating own datasources I need to provide @Column